# C errors: implicit declaration of function and storage size isn't known, despite the function and struct being members of an included header file

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, findfirst

I'm trying to make a test program that simply searches for any file in its root folder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <dos.h>

struct ffblk ffblk;

int main(){
    int result = findfirst("*.*", &ffblk,FA_ARCH);
    return 0;
}
```

But when the code compiles, the `ffblk` `struct` declaration returns the error:

> storage size of ffblk isn't known

and the `findfirst()` function returns:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'findfirst'[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

[as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F49oF.png), even though both `findfirst` and `ffblk` are members of `dir.h`, which is already included. I'm using `Visual Studio` and compiling with `GCC`. Does someone know what is wrong with the code, or the header files?

Comment: Q: Have you considered trying what the warnings tell you to do? `<dos.h> is obsolete: consider using <direct.h> instead.` and `<dir.h> is obsolete, consider using <io.h> instead.`.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Try substituting "io.h" and "direct.h", 2) consider using `struct ffblk f;`.

Comment: Yes. findfirst() is still said to be implicitly declared, and the storage size of the struct still isn't known, the only thing that changes is the name.

Comment: You want [`_findfirst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzxfzac.aspx).

Comment: You want to see if you can use headers from this century :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really, really shouldn't be using obsolete APIs from obsolete headers like "dos.h" if you can at all avoid it.  Honest!

Nevertheless, if you *insist*...

1. As dbush pointed out, the actual (obsolete!) API is `_findfirst` (not `findfirst`).
2. It is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzxfzac.aspx)
3. You'll see that the argument for this (again - *OBSOLETE*) API is `struct _finddata_t *fileinfo` (not `struct ffblk`).

Change your code, and everything should compile and run.

Better, change your headers (to "io.h" and "dir.h") - and the original code should probably compile and run.

Comment: Thanks! I was following an example code from a 2014 post that copied itself to other files on the folder, and it used both dos.h and dir.h, and findfirst() instead of _findfirst(). I didn't think that a header would be **really** obsolete for a language as old as C.

Comment: Platforms (like "dos") come and go - C is Forever :)